# Growth Curve Models using lmer() function in R (lme4 package)

Tags: lme4-nlme, panel-data, multilevel-analysis, growth-model

I am interested in changes in depression surrounding different life events and if personality traits (level-2 predictors) affect these changes in depression. In a given longitudinal data set, each subjects depression has been measured annually 9 times (or how often someone participated in the panel) as well as if a life event has occurred (measured monthly!). I created an event-centered time variable so that -1 represents the measurement occasion one month ahead of the event and +1 would be one month after the event.

I tried to start with an unconditional growth model with *months surrounding the event* as time predictor:

gcm.RS <- lmer(dep ~ 1 + event1.months + 
                           (1 + event1.months | id), data=event1)

Unfortunately I get the following warning message:

[image: warning message]

What does this mean? Has it something to do with my time variable?

In a next step I would like to test whether subjects differ in their change trajectories, and after that if personality explains the inter-individual differences in the intra-individual change curves. I thought to grand-mean center personality first. As this is my first-time use of lme4 I'm quite unsure if my procedure is right? Your comments on this are highly appreciated!

My ideas for these next models would be:

gcm.RI <- lmer(dep ~ 1 + event1.months + 
                           (1 | id), data=event1)

anova(gcm.RI, gcm.RS, refit=FALSE)

If subjects differ in their change curve I would stick to the RS model.

and for extraversion as an example:

attach(event1)

extrav.cgm <- extrav - mean(tapply(extrav, id, mean, na.rm=TRUE), na.rm=TRUE)

detach(event1)

gcm.CLI.extra <- lmer(dep ~ 1 + event1.months * extrav.cgm + 
                        (1 + event1.months | id), data=event1)

It would be an incredible help if you could let me know (1) what this warning messing means and subsequently what I am supposed to change and (2) if my other models are correct?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The first thing to try is to take up its suggestion of rescaling variables. If that fails try the R-sig-mixed-models mailing list where experts on this hang out.

Comment: Although  this is posed with R, it's really a stats problem so I am voting to leave it open.